# Using a minus product price in WooCommerce 2.0

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

for a webshop (WooCommerce 2.0) i want to create a product witch have a negative amount (example €-7,00). This is for a plastic bottle (in Holland we have "Statiegeld"). Is it possible for WooCommerce to create a product with a negative price? In the older version of WooCommerce this was possible.

Comment: Are you talking about a deposit? That means the customer will get some money back if he returns the bottle?

Comment: It is some kind of deposid, example you buy a bottle and the deposid is 7 euro this amount will be plus the amount of the bottle. On the shop it must be possible that buyers can return the bottles. So they get a credit invoice.

Comment: Ok, but then you don't need a negative price, because you (as a shop) are not selling something, but technically you're buying the bottle back. So you have to book a retuned bottle as a return (same thing as if the customer returns a product and wants his money back - if you offer that).

Comment: True, but we want to buy the bottles back. example a customer have 7 empty bottles and want to buy 3 full bottles we want to a product that make it possible to buy the bottles back. the VAT is set to 0. in the older version of WooCommerce it was possible to have a negative price product. is it possible to have it also on WooCommerce 2.0? and how?

Comment: I don't know this WooCommerce product, I can only give you general tipps. But I think that you're going the wrong way to model your requirement. You will not need to model this with negative prices, you will have to model this as a return.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what our neighbors built for their Flaschenpfand: https://github.com/nerdissimo-de/woocommerce-pfand